# Convert swift3 list to json

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I'm looking for a way to convert Swift3 List

```
var myList = [MyObject]();
```

to json.

I used:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myList, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
```

the application crashed.

Comment: What actually you trying to do, question is unclear. First read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: You can't serialize custom objects with `JSONSerialization`. You have to convert them to a JSON compliant type (array of dictionary / dictionary). And in Swift 3 do not use `NSData` and `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()`. Use `Data` and omit the `options` parameter. And structs and classes are supposed to start with a capital letter.

Comment: json in swift works only with dictionary or arrays? because in java and c# you can send a list to json serializer and it will create a json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize an Array / List, the issue is the custom `MyObject`, you have to map that to a Dictionary first.

I would use the `.map` method:

```
var myList = [MyObject]() // myList contains MyObject's
let jsonArray = myList.map { obj in
  return obj.serialize()
}
```

Than in `MyObject` add a serialize function, something like this:

```
public func serialize() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
  var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()

  // now place all your public vars in the dictionary
  dict["id"] = self.id
  dict["name"] = self.name
  dict["title"] = self.title

  return dict
}
```

Now if you want to deserialize just create another method:

```
public func deserialize(source: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
  // You might need some type conversion
  self.id = source["id"]
  self.name = source["name"]
  self.title = source["title"]
}
```

And call map again, now from `Dictionary` to `MyObject`:

```
var jsonArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() // jsonArray contains dictionaries
let myList = jsonArray.map { dict in
  let obj = MyObject()
  obj.deserialize(source: dict)

  return obj
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you now how i make deserialize json to array with MyObject?